# Python Columns Merge

Tags: python, pandas

For example lets say I have two columns A and B

```
A  B
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

---

And, I want to convert the above pandas dataframe to the below example. I tried `merge` but I am getting duplicate values.

```
A_X B_X       A_Y  B_Y

1    2         2     3
1    2         3     4
1    2         4     5
2    3         3     4
2    3         4     5
3    4         4     5
```

Comment: Hi. What code did you use to try to merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df.assign(key=1).merge(df.assign(key=1), on='key')\
  .query('A_x != A_y and B_x != B_y').drop('key', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A_x  B_x  A_y  B_y
1     1    2    2    3
2     1    2    3    4
3     1    2    4    5
4     2    3    1    2
6     2    3    3    4
7     2    3    4    5
8     3    4    1    2
9     3    4    2    3
11    3    4    4    5
12    4    5    1    2
13    4    5    2    3
14    4    5    3    4
```

Or to filter further use inequalities:

```
df.assign(key=1).merge(df.assign(key=1), on='key')\
  .query('A_x < A_y and B_x < B_y').drop('key', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A_x  B_x  A_y  B_y
1     1    2    2    3
2     1    2    3    4
3     1    2    4    5
6     2    3    3    4
7     2    3    4    5
11    3    4    4    5
```

Details:

`assign` a pseudo key and 'self-join' using `merge` to create a cartesian product
then use `query` to filter the results and `drop` the key.

Comment: Thank you for your help, need small modification row 4 and row 1 are equal, so I don't want columns to get  repeated in that way

Comment: @Sandeep I think I have that fixed with the 'filter further' option using <'s.  Please confirm.